# iOS 13 Large Navigation bar appearance + Tabbar images

Tags: swift, uitabbar, navigationbar, ios13

I have wired UI for navigation bar in iOS 13 simulator and tabbar images

[image]

ScreenShot of 12.1

[image]

I have used following settings

```
func setupNavbarAndTabbar() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isOpaque = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryDark")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:Constants.AppTheme.Fonts.font(type: .FONT_BOLD, size: 19) ,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes   = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:Constants.AppTheme.Fonts.font(type: .FONT_BOLD, size: 34) ,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]



    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryDark")
    UITabBar.appearance().isOpaque = true
 //   UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false


    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage.init(color: UIColor(named: "PrimaryDark")!, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))

    //Set Shadow Color
 //   UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.init(color: UIColor.init(red: 10/255.0, green: 14/255.0, blue: 19/255.0, alpha: 1.0), size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)) //UIImage.colorForNavBar(color: UIColor.init(red: 120/255.0, green: 120/255.0, blue: 120/255.0, alpha: 1.0))

}
```

For Tabbar

```
    tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -1)
    tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.init(red: 10/255.0, green: 14/255.0, blue: 19/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
```

I don't want **translucent** navigation bar

Any Help or suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the second image is your expected navigationBar and tabbar ?

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh Yes this is screenshot of ios12 where it is working fine. first screenshot is ios13 where it is show black bar on top

Comment: Hello. Same issue, have you find any solution?

Comment: @iOSDev Nope ,  I have to `UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I just found how to customize navigation bar in iOS 13, just use UINavigationBarAppearance.

Comment: @iOSDev You can add it as answer If it really works

Comment: What is name of this app?

Comment: @mahan Under development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I customize the navigation bar with iOS 13 support:

```
extension UINavigationBar
{
    class func setupAppearance()
    {
        let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *)
        {
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.backgroundColor = .darkGray
            appearance.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
            appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = textAttributes

            self.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
            self.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
            self.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
            self.appearance().tintColor = .white
            self.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true
        }
        else
        {
            self.appearance().isTranslucent = false
            self.appearance().barTintColor = .darkGray
            self.appearance().tintColor = .white
            self.appearance().barStyle = .black

            self.appearance().titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
            {
                self.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = textAttributes
                self.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.